# How can I dynamically type cast a value in Scala?

Tags: scala

I want to the equivalent of x.asInstanceOf[T] when I don't know T until runtime.  (I'm using Dotty, so Scala reflection is not available.)

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```scala
object DynaCaster:

  def cast( victim: Any, asA: Class[_] ) =
    val classTag = ClassTag.apply(asA)
    _cast(victim)(classTag)

  private def _cast[T](v: Any)(implicit ct: ClassTag[T]): T = v.asInstanceOf[T]
```

Intended use:

```scala
val x: SomeThing = ... // where SomeThing is a case class extending trait AnyThing
val anyThingValue = DynaCaster.cast(x, Class.forName("com.mystuff.AnyThing"))

// anyThingValue is now of class AnyThing
// Note: My actual use case cannot know the end types beforehand.  For example, this won't 
// work for my use:
// val anyThingValue: AnyThing = ...
```

What's my mysterious use case?  I'm dynamically calling a class constructor obtained via Java reflection.  Its arguments are typed to a trait, while the actual arg values are typed to concrete classes of that trait.  I need to dynamically cast the concrete class values to their trait types in order to invoke the constructor.

Comment: `Class.forName().cast(x)` would work from Java so can be called from Scala.

Comment: "I need to dynamically cast the concrete class values to their trait types in order to invoke the constructor." I don't think you do. It just takes `Object`s... https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance-java.lang.Object...-